# MS Excel: How to get cell value matching multiple criteria without using Array Formula

Tags: excel-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create an Excel File to keep track of usage of Paper Rolls in my Corrugated Box Manufacturing Factory. We identify each Paper Roll with a unique Roll Number and their usage is tracked using the same.

Every time a roll is issued from the store, it is weighed and the weight is recorded as **Quantity Issued**. Partially used rolls are returned to the store and that weight is recorded as **Quantity Returned (0 in case the roll is completely used)**.

I have created a table as below using an array formula

```
{=IF(COUNTIF($C$3:[@[Roll Number]], [@[Roll Number]]) = 1, INDEX(T_RollStock[Purchased Qty (kg)],MATCH([@[Roll Number]],T_RollStock[Roll Number],0)), INDEX([Quantity Returned (kg)], SMALL( IF([Roll Number]=[@[Roll Number]], ROW([Roll Number]) - ROW( INDEX([Roll Number],1,1) )+1 ), COUNTIF($C$3:[@[Roll Number]], [@[Roll Number]])-1)))}
```

[image]

If the Roll Number is appearing for the first time in the table, then the **Quantity Issued** will be the **Quantity Purchased**. If its not the first occurrence, it checks the ***second last occurrence*** of the Roll Number and returns the **Quantity Returned**.

I am trying to check the following conditions to auto-generate **Quantity Issued**:

1. **Roll issued for the first time:** Quantity Issued = Quantity Purchased
2. **Partially used roll issued at later stages:** Check for the `Max[Returned Date] < [@[Issued Date]]` and return ***Quantity Returned***.
3. **Roll issued multiple times on a single day:** Check for the `Max[Returned Date] <= [@[Issued Date]]` and `Second Last Occurrence` return ***Quantity Returned***.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

I used two **helper columns** to solve your case without using array formula. In the above example I have added some test data highlighted in yellow.

**Helper1** used **COUNTIF** to return the index number per paper roll number `PRN` if the data has been sorted by `ISSD Issued Date` in ascending order:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)
```

**EDIT #2** If the dates are not sorted, please use the following **Array Formula** to return the index number:

```
=MATCH(B2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ISSD/(PRN=A2),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(PRN,A2)))),0)+(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)-1)
```

> you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise they will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.

**Helper2** is used to create a **unique index reference** per `PRN`:

```
=A2&"#"&E2
```

**QTYISD** which is quantity issued is calculated as:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([QTYRE],MATCH(A2&"#"&(E2-1),[Helper2],0)),INDEX(T_RollStock[QTYPUR],MATCH(A2,T_RollStock[PRN],0)))
```

> the formula is trying to find the `quantity returned` base on the previous **unique index reference**, and if there is no previous return, it must be the first issue, so the formula will return the `quantity purchased` from the second table on the right per `PRN`.

**QTYUSD** which is quantity used is simply the difference between issued and returned:

```
=G2-D2
```

Drag the formulas down to apply across.

Comment: Thanks Terry, would it be possible to include the check for dates as well ? Because that's where I'm stuck badly.

Comment: @ChandanDNadig have you tested my solution and if so please let me know what I have missed or did not cover? I am not too sure about what you mean by check for dates?

Comment: My understanding is, if the dates are not sorted then the index number will simply be assigned based on occurrence. Am I correct ?

Comment: @Chandan D Nadig i thought your row data was in date order. If it is not the case, then you probably should sort it so the first occurrence can be determined correctly.

Comment: Link to download Dummy File 

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai99VQJGegiPhBGMLi7xAUpaCWke?e=roHcAg

Comment: @ChandanDNadig I have updated my solution (**EDIT#2**) to show you how to find the index number in another way if the dates are not sorted. Let me know if you have any questions. P.s. I would recommend to sort the dates instead of using array formula which is taking more memory and calculation time but it is your choice to make :)